# ¿Por qué los envíos POST de mi formulario HTML se registran en mi BBDD en campos desordenados?

Tags: javascript, html, post, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un formulario `HTML` que envía los datos con `method="post"` a una hoja de `google sheet`.
El problema es que los envía, pero los datos ingresan desordenados a la hoja.
He chequeado los `name` del formulario `HTML`, la hoja de `Google Sheet`, y el código en el `script` de `Google Apps Script`, y están todos en el orden requerido.
Sin embargo, el problema persiste. Ya no entiendo si el error es proveniente del formulario `html` o del `script` en `google apps script` (aunque creo que es aquí).
Los problemas actuales en total son los siguientes: 1) No me trae `Date`, y 2) los campos se registran todos desordenados. Ej: Ingresa `cuil` en la columna de `nombre`; `email` en la columna de `provincia`; etc. Y en otro envío capaz me trae `situacion-laboral` en la columna `nombre` y así los errores constantes en los ingresos en todas las columnas. Cabe mencionar que además posee un re-direccionamiento mediante `return HtmlService` aunque creo no debería ser ese el problema...

**Copio el script completo de Google Apps Script (con datos de prueba)**

```
function doPost(e) {
    try {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("XXX");
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
        
        // Mapeo de campos con columnas en la hoja de Google Sheet
        var fieldToColumn = {
          'dinero-necesitas': 'A',
          'nombre': 'B',
          'apellido': 'C',
          'cuil': 'D',
          'situacion-laboral': 'E',
          'provincia': 'F',
          'banco-cobro': 'G',
          'telefono': 'H',
          'email': 'I',
        };
        
        // Ordena los datos en el mismo orden que las columnas de la hoja de cálculo
        rowData.sort(function(a, b) {
          return fieldToColumn[a] - fieldToColumn[b];
        });
        
        // Agrega la fecha actual al registro
        rowData.push(new Date());
        
        // Crea la columna "Fecha"
        sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("Fecha");
        
        // Encuentra la última fila no vacía en la columna A
        var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
        
        // Inserta la fila en la hoja, respetando el orden de las columnas
        sheet.appendRow(["dinero-necesitas","nombre","apellido","cuil","situacion-laboral","provincia","banco-cobro","telefono","email"])
        
        // Redirecciona al usuario a la página deseada
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>window.location.href = "https://www.ejemplo.com";</script>');
    } catch (error) {
        return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error al registrar: " + error.message); // En caso de error, responde con un mensaje de error
    }
}
```

**Y aquí el código del formulario HTML (con datos de prueba)**

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Solicitud de Crédito</title>
<style>
    .form-container {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .form-group {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .form-group label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        color: #0077c0;
    }

    .form-group input,
    .form-group select {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 8px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .form-group input[type="submit"] {
        background-color: #0077c0;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .form-group .file-upload {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .form-group .file-upload input[type="file"] {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .form-group .file-upload .button {
        padding: 8px 16px;
        background-color: #0077c0;
        color: white;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        text-align: justify;
    }
</style>

<script src="validation.js">
function validateForm() {
    // Get the value of the hidden field.
    var columnName = document.getElementById("columnName").value;

    // Get the value of the first field in the form.
    var firstFieldValue = document.getElementById("firstField").value;

    // Check if the values match.
    if (columnName != firstFieldValue) {
      // The values do not match.
       alert("Los valores no coinciden. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo.");
       return false;
    }

    // The values match.
    return true;
}
```

```
<div class="form-container">
    <h2 style="color: #0077c0;">Solicitud de Crédito</h2>
    <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/exec" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="credit-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dinero-necesitas" style="color: #80c342;">¿Cuánto dinero necesitas?</label>
            <input type="range" id="dinero-necesitas" name="dinero-necesitas" min="10000" max="250000" step="1000" required="">
            <input type="hidden" name="dinero-necesitas" value="dinero-necesitas">
            <output for="dinero-necesitas" id="output-dinero-necesitas" style="color: #0077c0;">$100.000</output>
            <script>
                var slider = document.getElementById("dinero-necesitas");
                var output = document.getElementById("output-dinero-necesitas");

                slider.oninput = function() {
                    var value = Number(this.value).toLocaleString('es-AR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'ARS' });
                    output.innerHTML = value;
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Tu Nombre" required="">
            <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" placeholder="Tu Apellido" required="">
            <input type="hidden" name="apellido" value="apellido">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="cuil" name="cuil" placeholder="CUIL" pattern="[0-9]{11}" required="">
            <small style="color: #0077c0;">El CUIL debe tener 11 dígitos.</small>
            <input type="hidden" name="cuil" value="cuil">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="situacion-laboral" name="situacion-laboral" required="">
                <option value="">Selecciona tu situación laboral</option>
                <option value="Administración Pública Nacional">Administración Pública Nacional</option>
                <option value="Fuerzas de Seguridad Nacional">Fuerzas de Seguridad Nacional</option>
                <option value="Fuerzas Armadas Nacionales">Fuerzas Armadas Nacionales</option>
                <option value="Empleado/a PÚBLICO/A Provincial">Empleado/a PÚBLICO/A Provincial</option>
                <option value="Empleado/a PÚBLICO/A Municipal">Empleado/a PÚBLICO/A Municipal</option>
                <option value="Empleado/a PRIVADO/A">Empleado/a PRIVADO/A</option>
                <option value="Jubilado/a-Pensionado/a ANSES">Jubilado/a-Pensionado/a ANSES</option>
                <option value="Jubilado/a-Pensionado/a PROVINCIAL">Jubilado/a-Pensionado/a PROVINCIAL</option>
                <option value="Beneficio 40 Pensión Graciable">Beneficio 40 Pensión Graciable</option>
                <option value="Otros Beneficios ANSES">Otros Beneficios ANSES</option>
                <option value="Autónomo/Monotributo">Autónomo/Monotributo</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="situacion-laboral" value="situacion-laboral">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="provincia" name="provincia" required="">
                <option value="">Selecciona una provincia</option>
                <option value="Buenos Aires">Buenos Aires</option>
                <option value="CABA">Ciudad Autónoma de Buenos Aires</option>
                <option value="Catamarca">Catamarca</option>
                <option value="Chaco">Chaco</option>
                <option value="Chubut">Chubut</option>
                <option value="Córdoba">Córdoba</option>
                <option value="Corrientes">Corrientes</option>
                <option value="Entre Ríos">Entre Ríos</option>
                <option value="Formosa">Formosa</option>
                <option value="Jujuy">Jujuy</option>
                <option value="La Pampa">La Pampa</option>
                <option value="La Rioja">La Rioja</option>
                <option value="Mendoza">Mendoza</option>
                <option value="Misiones">Misiones</option>
                <option value="Neuquén">Neuquén</option>
                <option value="Río Negro">Río Negro</option>
                <option value="Salta">Salta</option>
                <option value="San Juan">San Juan</option>
                <option value="San Luis">San Luis</option>
                <option value="Santa Cruz">Santa Cruz</option>
                <option value="Santa Fe">Santa Fe</option>
                <option value="Santiago del Estero">Santiago del Estero</option>
                <option value="Tierra del Fuego">Tierra del Fuego</option>
                <option value="Tucumán">Tucumán</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="provincia" value="provincia">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select id="banco-cobro" name="banco-cobro" required="">
                <option value="">Selecciona tu banco de cobro</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE GALICIA Y BUENOS AIRES S.A.U.">BANCO DE GALICIA Y BUENOS AIRES S.A.U.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE LA NACION ARGENTINA">BANCO DE LA NACION ARGENTINA</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE LA PROVINCIA DE BUENOS AIRES">BANCO DE LA PROVINCIA DE BUENOS AIRES</option>
                <option value="BANCO ICBC">BANCO ICBC</option>
                <option value="CITIBANK N.A.">CITIBANK N.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO BBVA ARGENTINA S.A.">BANCO BBVA ARGENTINA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE LA PROVINCIA DE CORDOBA S.A.">BANCO DE LA PROVINCIA DE CORDOBA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO SUPERVIELLE S.A.">BANCO SUPERVIELLE S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE LA CIUDAD DE BUENOS AIRES">BANCO DE LA CIUDAD DE BUENOS AIRES</option>
                <option value="BANCO PATAGONIA S.A.">BANCO PATAGONIA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO HIPOTECARIO S.A.">BANCO HIPOTECARIO S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE SAN JUAN S.A.">BANCO DE SAN JUAN S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO MUNICIPAL DE ROSARIO">BANCO MUNICIPAL DE ROSARIO</option>
                <option value="BANCO SANTANDER ARGENTINA S.A.">BANCO SANTANDER ARGENTINA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DEL CHUBUT S.A.">BANCO DEL CHUBUT S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE SANTA CRUZ S.A.">BANCO DE SANTA CRUZ S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE LA PAMPA">BANCO DE LA PAMPA</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE CORRIENTES S.A.">BANCO DE CORRIENTES S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO PROVINCIA DEL NEUQUÉN S.A.">BANCO PROVINCIA DEL NEUQUÉN S.A.</option>
                <option value="BRUBANK S.A.U.">BRUBANK S.A.U.</option>
                <option value="BIBANK S.A.">BIBANK S.A.</option>
                <option value="HSBC BANK ARGENTINA S.A.">HSBC BANK ARGENTINA S.A.</option>
                <option value="OPEN BANK ARGENTINA S.A.">OPEN BANK ARGENTINA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO CREDICOOP COOP. LTADO.">BANCO CREDICOOP COOP. LTADO.</option>
                <option value="BANCO ITAU ARGENTINA S.A.">BANCO ITAU ARGENTINA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO PROVINCIA DE TIERRA DEL FUEGO">BANCO PROVINCIA DE TIERRA DEL FUEGO</option>
                <option value="BANCO MACRO S.A.">BANCO MACRO S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO COMAFI S.A.">BANCO COMAFI S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO RIOJA S.A.U.">BANCO RIOJA S.A.U.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DEL SOL S.A.">BANCO DEL SOL S.A.</option>
                <option value="NUEVO BANCO DEL CHACO S. A.">NUEVO BANCO DEL CHACO S. A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE FORMOSA S.A.">BANCO DE FORMOSA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO DE SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO S.A.">BANCO DE SANTIAGO DEL ESTERO S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO INDUSTRIAL S.A.">BANCO INDUSTRIAL S.A.</option>
                <option value="NUEVO BANCO DE SANTA FE S.A.">NUEVO BANCO DE SANTA FE S.A.</option>
                <option value="WILOBANK S.A.U.">WILOBANK S.A.U.</option>
                <option value="NUEVO BANCO DE ENTRE RÍOS S.A.">NUEVO BANCO DE ENTRE RÍOS S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO COLUMBIA S.A.">BANCO COLUMBIA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO BICA S.A.">BANCO BICA S.A.</option>
                <option value="BANCO COINAG S.A.">BANCO COINAG S.A.</option>
                <option value="Otro Banco No Listado">Otro Banco No Listado</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="banco-cobro" value="banco-cobro">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="tel" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Número WhatsApp" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required="">
            <small style="color: #0077c0;">El número debe tener 10 dígitos (ejemplo: 3519999999).</small>
            <input type="hidden" name="telefono" value="telefono">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" required="">
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="email">
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Generar Solicitud">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<footer>
    <p>
        INFORMACIÓN FINANCIERA: XXX
    </p>
</footer>

<script>
var form = document.getElementById('credit-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Obtener los datos del formulario
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    // Enviar los datos al script de Google Apps Script
    fetch(form.action, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.text();
        } else {
            throw new Error('Error al enviar el formulario');
        }
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        // Mostrar mensaje de confirmación
        alert(data);
        form.reset(); // Limpiar el formulario después del envío

        // Redireccionar al usuario a la página deseada
        window.location.href = 'https://www.ejemplo.com';
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert('Hubo un error al enviar el formulario.');
    });
});

var slider = document.getElementById("dinero-necesitas");
var output = document.getElementById("output-dinero-necesitas");

slider.oninput = function() {
    var value = Number(this.value).toLocaleString('es-AR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'ARS' });
    output.innerHTML = value;
};
</script>
```

**Nota:** Al ingresar el código lo copió separado. No trajo la apertura del script en el formulario HTML, pero está.

Comment: Era más claro con la imagen! No dividas el código, copia lo mismo que tenias en la imagen y ponlo como texto. Abre el monitor de red del navegador y realiza la solicitud POST. Luego buscas  el registro en el monitor de red y mira la pestaña "carga útil" para determinar si los datos son enviados correctamente o no (así sabemos quien es el culpable)

Comment: Listo! Código del Script en las modificaciones (con datos de prueba). Agradezco la comprensión. Soy nuevo en el foro. Mientras tanto estoy viendo el monitor de red.

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los problemas es que `rowData` no está definido en el código de Google Apps Script mostrado.